# Can File Maker Server 5 Run under windows server 2008 or 2012

Tags: filemaker

I am working with a client that is running Filemaker Server 5 in a workgroup environment and is now upgrading to a true client server network running either MS windows server 2008 or 2012. Will Filemaker Server 5 run in the new network environment. They do not want to upgrade Filemaker. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[FileMaker Server operating system requirements - all versions](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5677/~/filemaker-server-operating-system-requirements---all-versions)

Windows 2008 does not appear on the list until FileMaker 10. Windows 2012 only supported only with FileMaker 13.

This is an official supported version chart, so you still can try and install it. I am sure, there is a compatibility mode which will let you run it. If you have any problem, you will not be able to get any support from FileMaker.

If updating FileMaker is such an issue, you might be better of running a VM on the same server with an older OS and serve it from there.

You will probably have a similar problem with clients' installs when their workstations are upgraded. FileMaker 15 is around 15 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider that the filemaker 5 / 6 clients will not install on a new OSX OS Version - I'm not sure about Windows, that should be tested before moving forward if that is a requirement.

All new versions of Filemaker will convert Filemaker 5 files to a new format, however it's a big change and the scripting and layouts need to be checked after conversion.  Filemaker 5 is 14+ years old and support stopped around 10 years ago which explains the compatibility issues.